# How to replace some spaces with hyphens using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm doing some wiki/markdown transformations, and have string like this:

```
[[Moo Cow]]
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
[Moo Cow](Moo-Cow.html)
```

How can I do this using `sed`?

Comment: Aren't you looking to do more than replace spaces with hyphens?

Comment: could be there more than 2 words, like `[[Some Foo Bar Cow]]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your sed expression like this:

```
sed -i 's/\[\[\([^]]*\)]]/[\1](\1.html)/g;:a;s/\(]([^) ]*\) /\1-/g;ta;' file
```

or with perl:

```
perl -pe's/\[\[([^]]*)]]/$a=$1;$a=~y# #-#;"[$1]($a.html)"/ge' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `sed` command that will do that for you:

```
sed -i 's/\]\]/\]\(\.html\)/g; s/\[\[/\[/g; s/\[\(.*\)\](\.html)/\[\1\](\1.html)/g; :a;s/\(([^)]*\) /\1-/;ta' filename.md
```

No, that is not pretty.  Yes, that is ugly.  But, it works.

Comment: It does work with GNU `sed`, even for multiple words within the `[[multiple words here]]` and with multiple words outside.  However, it runs into problems if there is more than one `[[Magic Pattern]]` on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[][]/,""); x=$0; gsub(/ /,"-"); printf "[%s](%s).html\n", x, $0}' file
[Moo Cow](Moo-Cow).html
```